# Cannot find the log4j siftAppender output logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j, sift, sifting-appender

I followed this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/serivcemix-configuring-sift)

I have this code, but no log file was written.

What am i missing?

here is my [code](https://github.com/elad2109/log4j_sift/blob/master/src/main/java/com/waze/rr_logger/SiftExampleLog4j.java): https://github.com/elad2109/log4j_sift/blob/master/src/main/java/com/waze/rr_logger/SiftExampleLog4j.java

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class SiftExampleLog4j {

    static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SiftExampleLog4j.class);

    public void log() {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("session_id","MyGooApp");

        logger.error("example1");

        org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("session_id","MyFooApp");

        logger.error("example2");
    }
}
```

log4j.properties

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, sift, osgi:VmLogAppender

# Sift appender
log4j.appender.sift=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
log4j.appender.sift.key=session_id
log4j.appender.sift.default=no_session_id
log4j.appender.sift.appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %m%n
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=$\\{session_id\\}.log
log4j.appender.sift.appender.append=true
```

I expect to see 2 output log files: `MyGooApp.log` and `MyFooApp.log`. However I cannot find them anywhere.

**Update**

I have tried this:

```
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=./$\\{session_id\\}.log
```

and yet I see now output files:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using logback. I am now sharing with you.

### SiftExample.java

```
package chapters.appenders.sift;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator;
import ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException;

public class SiftExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JoranException {
        String configFile = "F://logbackfile/logback.xml";

        LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SiftExample.class);
        logger.debug("Application started");

        lc.reset();
        lc.putProperty("appname", "MyGooApp");
        configurator.setContext(lc);
        configurator.doConfigure(configFile);
        logger.debug("Alice says hello");

        lc.reset();
        lc.putProperty("appname", "MyFooApp");
        configurator.setContext(lc);
        configurator.doConfigure(configFile);
        logger.debug("Bob says hi");
    }

    static void usage(String msg) {
        System.err.println(msg);
        System.err.println("Usage: java " + SiftExample.class.getName() + " configFile\n" + "   configFile a logback configuration file");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

### logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="F://logbackfile" />
    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/${appname}.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="chapters.appenders.sift" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

### Output:

**MyGooApp.log**

```
2016-05-09 01:35:57 - Alice says hello
```

**MyFooApp.log**

```
2016-05-09 01:35:57 - Bob says hi
```

---

### N.B: Please don't forget to do that

1. Package name `chapters.appenders.sift` is added in **logback.xml** as `<logger name="chapters.appenders.sift" level="debug" ...`

Comment: i have to use log4j as I'm appending to an existing production code and I want to add to existing configuration only

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using a relative path as filename (`log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=$\\{session_id\\}.log`).

If you set the log level for log4j to debug you should see within the generated logs a statement as follows:

```
setFile called: "+fileName+"
```

You can enable log4j internal logging by defining the log4j.configDebug variable. All log4j internal debug calls go to System.out where as internal error messages are sent to System.err. All internal messages are prepended with the string "log4j: ".

As test you could also change your file property into something like:

```
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=./$\\{session_id\\}.log
```

`.` represents the current folder (usually the project root folder).

Comment: ` log4j internal logging` what does that mean? what is it used for?

Comment: `defining the log4j.configDebug variable` set it to what value?

Comment: Defining the key `log4j.configDebug` should already be enough to enable logging (see log4j code `LogLog`) but i guess it won't hurt if you set the value to true. Defining this value makes log4j print log4j-internal debug statements to System.out.

Comment: I have added in the properties file `log4j.configDebug = true` but it didn't help

Comment: Did you see a entry that started with `setFile called:` within your log?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here.

1. First move your log4j.properties from root of project to "`src/resources`". Then you will see a world of relevant errors.
2. Log4j jar does not have this package `org.apache.log4j.sift`, add supporting pax-logging jar to your classpath.
3. It will also help to use either Karaf OSGi MDC or Camel MDCbecause Apache Karaf uses Pax Logging as logging system. (I am not sure how it will work without the OSGi though)

Your problem is not with this line `log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=./$\\{session_id\\}.log`, as far as the path goes `./$\\{session_id\\}.log` should create the log file in your project root once you have everything else configured properly.

Comment: how come `Log4j jar does not have this package org.apache.log4j.sift`, look at this tutorial which doesn't suggest adding `pax-logging jar to your classpath.` tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/serivcemix-configuring-sift

Comment: You can yourself explode the jar file and see whether that package exists. Second, that tutorial does say `Lets have a look at the org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg of the latest distribution of Fuse ESB, which is currently 4.4.1-fuse-03-06.` which means it is using Karaf, that I already suggested. Also that tutorial mentions "org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg file", where do you think that comes from.